# ¿Cómo puedo crear un model desde un controlador en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Me gustaría saber como puedo crear un modelo desde un controlador, ya sé como crear una tabla pero, seguido de esta creación crear un model para después hacer inserts en la tabla creada anteriormente.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si adjuntas el código que tienes hecho , la comunidad podrá ayudarte mejor! Un saludo :)

Comment: No queda muy clara la pregunta. Para crear modelos utiliza el comando: `php artisan make:model NombreModelo`

Comment: Utiliza artisan para lo que deseas hacer: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#closure-commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen dos modos básicos de crear un modelo en Laravel, el comando *artisan* que nos proporciona a tal efecto, por ejemplo:

```
php artisan make:model MiModelo
```

Esto sería lo recomendable y más rápido, podemos o crear nosotros el fichero y añadir el código en su interior, bien con un editor de código o de algún otro modo...

Si por algún motivo necesitas crear un modelo en un controlador de Laravel, puedes o bien **llamar al comando artisan en el controlador**, o bien, **crear el fichero PHP** añadiendo el contenido como cualquier otro fichero de texto plano.

Para crear el modelo usando el comando artisan en un controlador, ponemos una línea como la que sigue en el método al que vamos a llamar para su creación:

```
\Artisan::call('make:model MiModelo');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Orici. Una ves use la línea de código que has comentado, para rellenar el model creado como podría hacerlo? no se puede pasar los parametros mediante el código Artisan::call('make:model MiModelo', ['campo1', 'campo2']); y a su vez establecer su correspondiente tabla como un model creado manualmente?.
La idea mia era automatizar este proceso para que cada vez que se genere digamos que un intento se creee un modelo, una tabla en la db con sus respectivos campos.

Comment: @Cristian_Salinas Para crear una tabla puedes usar una migración que puedes invocar por consola: php artisan `migrate --path=/database/migrations/the_migration.php` (o desde el controlador), como en el caso de crear el modelo, pero sólo va a funcionar una vez por migración (crea la tabla una vez). Al comando que usas para generar el modelo se le pueden pasar parámetros para diferentes acciones, como crear además la migración: `\Artisan::call('make:model MiModelo -m');` pero tendras que rellenarla manualmente o mediante código (se crea la estructura base)... después deberías ejecutarla.

Answer (score 0):

El modelo tienes que crearlo desde la consola con el comando: php artisan make:model 'NombredelModelo' .
No necesariamente tienes que seguir un flujo para crearlo.